# Query about Javascript (Callback and forEach)

Tags: javascript, callback, conditional-operator

So, I'm trying to use forEach to write a function named count(arr, callback).

It should, in theory, return the number of elements for which callback is true.

```
count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e === 3)
```

Expected: 1 but got: 0

```
count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e > 1)
```

Expected: 3 but got: 0

```
count([2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8], (e) => e === 2)
```

Expected: 2 but got: 0

Here is the code I am running:

```js
function count(arr, callback) {
  let values = 0;
  arr.forEach(callback) ? values++ : values;

  return values;
}
```

Comment: `.forEach` returns `undefined` ... every time ... no exception ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function count(arr, callback) {
  let values = 0;
  arr.forEach(item => callback(item) ? values++ : values);
  return values;
}

console.log(count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e === 3))
console.log(count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e > 1))
console.log(count([2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8], (e) => e === 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `filter`:

```js
const count = (arr, c) => arr.filter(c).length;

console.log(count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e === 3))
console.log(count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e > 1))
console.log(count([2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8], (e) => e === 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` ignores the return value of its callback. Use `reduce` instead:

```js
const count = (arr, cb) => arr.reduce((a, item) => a + cb(item), 0);

console.log(count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e === 3))
console.log(count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e > 1))
console.log(count([2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8], (e) => e === 2))
```